# Passing back data to first viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a basic understanding of how to handle swift protocols to pass data between two viewcontrollers. My situation is this: I wanted to pass data back to my first viewcontroller.

For example:

First ViewController

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, ViewControllerCResult {

    func set(data: String) {

    }

}
```

Second ViewController

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

}
```

Third ViewController

```
protocol ViewControllerCResult {
   set(data: String)
}

class ViewControllerC: UIViewController {
    var delegate: ViewControllerCResult?
}
```

ViewControllerA -> ViewControllerB -> ViewControllerC

I would like to pass data from ViewControllerC to ViewControllerA.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are they linked? For instance, is B a child of A,and C a child of B?

Comment: how did you instantiate your ViewControllers?

Comment: Just add `var delegate: ViewControllerCResult?` to `ViewControllerB ` too, then `ViewControllerB ` add the same one to `ViewControllerC `

Comment: Could you write why you need to pass data to first controller? A & C should never communicate. It's violating law of demeter.

Comment: Exactly @HackSaw , when I finish the task in C I perform a popViewController back to A, and wanted to return the result to A.

Comment: Might be better if C and B were children of A, even if that means B asking A to show C. This reflects the idea that A is the master controller, and B and C are subcontrollers of it. Then it's simply passing data to the parent.

Comment: are you using navigationcontroller to push and pop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: try to create block method.

Comment: I understood how to do it @HackSaw . It worked. I created a function that receives the values ​​and passed directly, since B and C are children of A.

Comment: I also managed to do protocols according to the answer @ShauketSheikh

Comment: @ThomasMarques good 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `Delegates` from Controller A -> B -> C , and when popViewcontroller will be called you can check the `self.delegate` in ViewController C, if it exist just call function like this `self.delegate?.set("data from c")`. Check

> popControllerPressed Function in ViewController3

**First View controller**

class ViewController: UIViewController, ViewControllerCResult {

```
var delegate: ViewControllerCResult?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func pushControllerPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as? ViewController2 {
        if let navigator = navigationController {
            viewController.delegate = self
            navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func set(data: String) {

}

}
```

**Second ViewController**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, ViewControllerCResult {

var delegate: ViewControllerCResult?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func pushControllerPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as? ViewController3 {
        if let navigator = navigationController {
            viewController.delegate = self.delegate
            navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func set(data: String) {
    print(data)
}

}
```

**Third ViewController**

```
protocol ViewControllerCResult {
   func set(data: String)
}
```

class ViewController3: UIViewController, ViewControllerCResult {

```
var delegate: ViewControllerCResult?

func set(data: String) {
    print(data)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func popControllerPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array {
        if controller.isKind(of: ViewController.self) {
            delegate?.set(data: "data from C")
            self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }

}

}
```

Here is Code Link: [Pass data forth and back](https://github.com/shauket/DataViewController.git)